# Google Sheets function to group and concat rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AeP0sxDi0-3aaesUdCNTKfricIimjTMFaKO-FX9_g50/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to find a formula that will group a table on a column and concat the values from all the rows in another column.

For example, if this is my table:

```
| name  | value   |
|-------|---------|
| one   | alpha   |
| two   | bravo   |
| three | charlie |
| one   | delta   |
| two   | echo    |
| four  | foxtrot |
| two   | golf    |
| three | hotel   |
| four  | india   |
```

This is what I want the formula to output:

```
| one   | alpha, delta      |
| two   | bravo, echo, golf |
| three | charlie, hotel    |
| four  | foxtrot, india    |
```

I wish I could share some formula that gets me close but I can't find anything. I thought maybe this formula but, as you can see from the sample sheet, it does not work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(", ", TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:B, A2:A = {UNIQUE(A2:A)}))))
```

My thought was, get a unique list of values in the `name` column, and then use `arrayformula` to get a list of values in the `value` column where the `name` column equals each value in the unique list. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&"♦", B2:B&","}, 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where Col1 !='' 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col1"),,999^99)), "♦")), ",$", ))
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A2:A), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&"♦", B2:B&","}, 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where Col1 !='' 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col1"),,999^99)), "♦")), ",$", ), {1, 2}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I was trying to achive the same, but I have more columns that need combining 

ID | ValueB | ValueC | .... ValueX


But I can't figure how to make it happen, how would this work if there are more collumns?

Comment: @Mikec as the answer for your case would differ I recon to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) the question

Comment: @player0 How about this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76700918/google-sheets-arrayformula-query-function-to-group-and-concat-rows-before-date